# Proof of $(ab)^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1}$

Tags: solution-verification

I wonder if you would consider this proof of my hypothesis of

$(ab)^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1}$ with $a,b\ne0$ correct.

By definition of the inverse of $ab$: $$(ab)^{-1}(ab)=1$$

Multiplying the equation with $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ gives $$(ab)^{-1}aba^{-1}b^{-1} = 1a^{-1}b^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$$ using property $1x=x$.
On the left hand side I rearrange the terms using the property $xy=yx$ to $$(ab)^{-1}aa^{-1}bb^{-1}= a^{-1}b^{-1}$$ which gives by using again the definition of the inverse $$(ab)^{-1}1\cdot1= a^{-1}b^{-1}$$
Using the property $1x=x$ on the left twice I have the answer.

Comment: It depends on what $a$ and $b$ are here. If $a$ and $b$ are elements of a group, not necessarily abelian, then the correct generalization is $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1} a^{-1}$.

Comment: I second Qiaochu Yuan's comment. For emphasis: what are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: This is sometimes called "socks and shoes".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is correct. You could even do this without assuming commutativity, but then you would get
$$(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}.$$

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, but this can be written more concisely as
$(ab)a^{-1}b^{-1}=a(ba^{-1})b^{-1}=a(a^{-1}b)b^{-1}=(aa^{-1})(bb^{-1})=1\cdot1=1$

The $a^{-1}b^{-1}(ab)$ case is similar.

Comment: Thank you for showing another approach.

Comment: You're welcome. I would have used from the start $(ba)a^{-1}b^{-b}$ but then you still have to use more steps with parentheses where you collapse the identity in between elements.

Comment: Okay but why would you have used that to start?

Comment: I meant I could have started $(ab)a^{-1}b^{-1} = (ba)a^{-1}b^{-1}$ instead of what I did, but there are actually atleast the same number of steps.

Answer (score 1):

$$(ab)^{-1}(ab)=1$$ $$ (ab)^{-1}abb^{-1}=b^{-1}$$ $$(ab)^{-1}a=b^{-1}$$  $$(ab)^{-1}aa^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$$ $$(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}.$$